# Using module feature as installable library

Tags: java, android

Actually, my app features are split into android library and I choose the feature I want include at the compile time. Is it possible to have a default app with very basic features, and an on-demand installable feature shipped as APK ?

I thought I could use module feature which was made for instant app because they are like android library but can generated APK but when I tried it out, the package name was different so it was impossible to use it.

I know it's the proper way to use android feature but can I use my own tricky way ? Otherwise, is there other possibilities to achieve this ?

Comment: is it something like flavour dimension ?

Comment: I don't think so. I won't choose the features at the compile time but during the runtime when a "feature apk" is installed.